# How to add calculated field to Summing up data in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a query table in MS Access having `ItemNumber` and `Quantity` fields. I want to add a calculated field `TotalQuantity` in table which summing up the Quantity of related items just like below:

```
=====================================
ItemNumber  Quantity    TotalQuantity
=====================================
INV-0001    10              45
INV-0001    20              45
INV-0001    15              45
INV-0002    5               23
INV-0002    8               23
INV-0002    10              23
INV-0003    4               9
INV-0003    5               9
```

Which formula may be used to adding this calculated field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a query with a subquery:

```
Select 
    ItemNumber, 
    Quantity, 
    (Select Sum(T.Quantity) 
    From YourTable As T
    Where T.ItemNumber = YourTable.ItemNumber) As TotalQuantity
From
    YourTable
```